# Command Line utility to see list of tasks CPU Usage, Memory, and execute

Tags: windows, command-line, memory, cpu, cpu-usage

I want to log, every 10 minutes, list of all the apps in windows that now running, the CPU usage, and memory usage.

I have many node.exe tasks, so I want to see the arguments of the task (for example: `node c:\myscript.js`

I tried: `tasklist/?` but didn't found anything related to cpu usage.

I tried: `procexp/?` but didn't found anyway to export the list to file (or show in console)

I tried: `cprocess` (NirSoft), it can dump to file, and show CPU, but it don't give the arguments of the exe that runned.

Any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the tool `typeperf`.

To list all processes:

```
typeperf "\Process(*)\% Processor Time" -sc 1
```

List all processes, take 5 samples at 10 second intervals:

```
typeperf "\Process(*)\% Processor Time" -si 10 -sc 5
```

If you want a specific process, node for example:

```
typeperf "\Process(node)\% Processor Time" -si 10 -sc 5
```

You also can dump it to a csv file and filter in a spreadsheet to remotely diagnose issues.

The following gives me 5 minutes (at 10 second intervals) of all processes. The data includes not just % Processor Time, but IO, memory, paging, etc.

```
typeperf -qx "\Process" > config.txt
typeperf -cf config.txt -o perf.csv -f CSV -y -si 10 -sc 60
```

More info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490960.aspx

Comment: Note:
  In order to use typeperf, you must either be a member of the local
  Performance Log Users group, or the command must be executed from an elevated command window.

Answer (score 3):

typeperf has two drawbacks:

1. `typeperf` with arguments as english names won't work on non-english machines, and
2. `typeperf` with arguments as numbers will break because those numbers vary by machine. (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39650695)

To avoid those drawbacks, you can use powershell's `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet.  It uses different names compared to typeperf, but you can get the same information, as far as I can tell.

I think that running these commands in powershell will give you what you want:

```
echo 'Map of process ID to command line:'
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Process" | Select-Object -Property ProcessId,ExecutablePath,CommandLine | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
echo 'Map of process ID to memory usage:'
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process" | Select-Object -Property IDProcess,Name,PageFileBytes,PoolNonpagedBytes,PoolPagedBytes,PrivateBytes,VirtualBytes,WorkingSet | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
echo 'Map of process ID to CPU usage:'
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process" | Select-Object -Property IDProcess,Name,PercentProcessorTime | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
echo 'Many people want to do some massaging of the "PercentProcessorTime" numbers above,'
echo 'because in their raw form those numbers (for a single process) can be over 100 percent.'
echo 'So divide all of the "PercentProcessorTime" numbers by this number:'
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem" | Select-Object -Property NumberOfLogicalProcessors | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

Without dependence on system localization:

> typeperf "\238(*)\6" -sc 1
>
> typeperf "\238(*)\6" -si 10 -sc 5
>
> typeperf "\238(_Total)\6" -si 10 -sc 5

Comment: To continuously save CPU usage per process, one should use something like this: `typeperf "\230(*)\6" -si 10 -o perf.csv -f CSV`, where 230 is the "Process" counter. 238 is the "Processor" counter as a whole (the command from the answer will show CPU usage per *core*, without tasks).

Answer (score 2):

If someone does not comfort with complicated PowerShell, I suggest [gotop](https://github.com/xxxserxxx/gotop). It is a handy CLI tool helps you check resource usage in beautiful interface.