# Command Line utility to see CPU Usage of a program/command (Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm using a Win 10 system and am unfamiliar with the command line arguments.

I tried [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1005945/command-line-utility-to-see-list-of-tasks-cpu-usage-memory-and-execute) but the output for each process looked like this "`\\JESSICAC-WS\Process(procname#1)\% Processor Time`" which is not helpful.

I would like to run a program (either by launching it via shortcut or on the command line) and measure its CPU usage as it runs. I would then like to consult the output in an external file of some kind.

What is the most efficient way to do this on Windows?

Comment: think you are look for "TASKLIST" more info here: https://superuser.com/questions/18830/is-there-a-command-in-windows-like-ps-aux-in-unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell you could do

```
while (1) { ps -Name <Process Name>| out-file log.txt -Append;  sleep -seconds 1}
```